# Month old iPad mini 4 has a yellow box outline on the screen! What should I do?

Tags: ipad, screen

[image]

I'm pretty sure this was not there before but now I just noticed it while reading on my iPad. I think it's only on the inside part of the screen as I cannot get the picture to show the yellow when I screenshot it...what should I do? Help! It's just over a month old!

Comment: Pure guess - you've enabled something in Setting>General>Accessibility; perhaps Voiceover ?

Comment: Regarding what you should do, I think @Mathias is right, as long as it's not been water damaged, Apple should replace it for free.

Comment: Is it related? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/236125/broken-ipad-screen

Answer (score -1):

[Make an appointment](https://www.apple.com/retail/geniusbar/) with a Genius in an Apple Store and they will swap it for a new one.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.