# Broken Ipad screen

Tags: ipad, screen

a few months a go, I opened my iPad to see my screen half blacked half works. I'm not sure what happened..
I attached a pic of its condition.

Does it look like a software issue or broken screen?
Can I buy and change the screen?
Is it worth it?[image]

Comment: its ipad2, or ipad 3...I cant remeber

Comment: This is absolutely a hardware issue and you'll need to replace the screen on the unit.

Comment: Does the touchscreen still work?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically there might be several reasons behind this issue:

- LCD cable has loose connection, and not attached firmly (highly probable, if you haven't dropped it);
- LCD screen is broken or it's controller went out of order;
- broken screen itself (very not probable, unless you dropped it).

I know the simple trick might help for certain cases:

- **a hard slap on the underside or sides of the device** – the screen might flicker screen back to life.

The screen has to be turned on, to see if slaps/shocks are helping. You need to watch if anything changes on the screen, flickering changes, it backs to normal, and then again doesn't work, or other symptoms. If you'll see the change - it will help you to diagnose the problem.

The screen itself is pretty expensive component in iPad, so the physical replacement would be costly for an old iPad, unless you can do it yourself. In most cases - guys are buying the new device, and the old one - they sell to repair-shops for a spare parts. Of course if you got top-notch version - it's easier to go to official repair-shop for replacement, they will give you warranty as well.

Comment: if someones decides to down-vote, please, write the reason below, why. This is real case, how **I fixed my device**, so welcome to argue, if you have the reason.. No joke.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hardware problem.  You can replace the screen, either do-it-yourself (there are several online guides) or take it into a place like iFixIt.  Depending on the device, a replacement will cost you between $100-$300.  You'll need to decide for yourself if it's worth it to get the screen replaced or buy a new iPad.